# Rendering content inside a partial via =yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I'm creating an application with ruby on rails where I have an items/_item.html.erb. Inside the partial is a yield statement so i can add extra content as needed. In this case, I want to add a specific button to item depending on what view calls partial.

This is what I've tried and it renders the partial, but it does not render the block:

**_item.html.erb**

```
<%= yield if block_given? %>
<div>
  <%= item.name %>
</div>
```

**someview.html.erb**

```
...

<% render(:partial => 'items/item', :collection => current_user.items do %>
  <%= "HELLO" %>      
<% end %>

...
```

I have also tried using content_for and some other stuff with no success. Is there a way to be able to render specific content inside a partial via yield? I'm currently using Rails3

EDIT:

I've found out that it's the :collection hash that makes it impossible insert the block.

Both of this pieces of code work:

```
<%= render :layout => 'items/item' do %>
      Hello world      
<% end %>

<%= render :layout => 'items/item', :locals => {:item => current_user.items.first} do %>
  Hello world      
<% end %>
```

This means that if i do a .each i could accomplish what I want but it would be ugly code. Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

`content_for` should work fine in this case. Here is the code I just double checked locally.

**somewhere.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :foobar do %>
  fubar
<% end %>
```

**_item.html.erb**

```
<% if content_for? :foobar %>
  <%= yield :foobar %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How are you working this out? I have tried setting the content_for code inside above, below and around the render and I still can't see the content being render with the partial. Is it because I'm using a collection as well?

Comment: In _item.html.erb we can use content_for instead of yield `<% content_for :foobar if content_for? :foobar %>`

Comment: Is there a chance you can throw a quick example of how the render call would look like?